# Eight lines and an eye

Tags: visual, poetry

Nine equals play (with dot inside) - 
Try to connect it all. 
Now tell exactly - what am I, 
and which direction do I go?

Comment: dubious use of the 'rhyme' tag here?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry It's a blank verse.

Comment: @rhsquared; technically neither blank nor free verse actually rhyme, so I've switched the tag to poetry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you:

> A fish swimming to the right (East)? 
>  [image]
>  This also matches the clue that the title provides since it take 8 lines and a dot (eye) to create the roman numeral "IX", the equal symbol (=), and the three lines of the "Play" symbol - and of course, the dot.

Comment: Thanks @gabbo1092, I couldn't get that image to hide with the spoiler markdown! lol